# What is IDLE stands for?

Tags: python, python-idle

I have using idle to solve python questions

Its a very simple question
idle
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqaf6.jpg)

Comment: Integrated Development and Learning Environment

Comment: The answer is the first part of the description of the `python-idle` tag.  Please look at tag descriptions before you use them.  You had 3 that are irrelevant to such a question.  Please accept the answer below so people browsing the list of questions will know that this is answered.

Answer (score 0):

IDLE stands for Integrated Development and Learning Environment. It is a built-in development environment for writing and running Python code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html first sentence: "IDLE is Python’s Integrated Development and Learning Environment."